# Android Studio - App Crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

How can I change or add more code to make this app to stop crashing? This activity is called "WhatBin", I simply wanted to make a button listen to when a person would click and change a text view. (VIEW PICTURES BELOW FOR MORE DETAILS.)

PICTURES: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK1b3.jpg

```
package com.example.tiffany.whatbin;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class WhatBin extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_what_bin);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 final TextView txt_answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_answer);

 Button btn_go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go);

    btn_go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txt_answer.setText("Marker - Recycle Bin");

        }
    });



    };
}
```

HERE IS THE XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     
android:layout_padddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_what_bin" tools:context=".WhatBin">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go"
    android:id="@+id/btn.go"
    android:layout_marginBottom="113dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/abc_dialog_material_background_dark"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textEdit"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn.go"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn.go"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn.go" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/instructiontext"
    android:id="@+id/textinstruc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textEdit"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn.go"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn.go" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/txt.1"
    android:id="@+id/txt.answer"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It looks like a problem in your layout file. Can you post your xml layout file?

Comment: Please post the error log as text so that we can read the error and pinpoint the problem. This also allows others to search for that specific error and find your question.

Comment: I have posted the XML file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You are currently using `abc_dialog_material_background_dark` as `textcolor`. As you can see in the [source of this resource](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/HEAD/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_dialog_material_background_dark.xml), it is basically a `shape`. And, `shape` cannot be used for `textcolor`.

---

In your XML file at `line 17` you have used a color. That color is of wrong type. My guess, you have used a drawable instead of a color.

Post your `activity_what_bin.xml` for further explanation.

Comment: I will post a  XML file. :)